# How to inject objects which are not annotated Spring classes

Tags: spring, javafx

Lets say I've got a JavaFx class and an ViewState class which needs to have referance of `stage` created in start method. How am I able to autowire such dependency? I know that `Stage.class` is not annotated as `@Component` so Spring is unable to detect duch `@Bean`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"controller","service","dao","javafx.stage.Stage"})
@EntityScan( basePackages = {"Model"})
@Import({ SpringConfig.class})
public class JavaFXandSpringBootTestApplication extends Application{

    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    ViewState viewState = ctx.getBean(ViewState.class);
}
```

ViewState class:

```
@Componenet
public class ViewState {

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext ctx;
private Stage stage;

@Autowired
public ViewState(Stage stage)
{
    this.stage = stage;
}
}
```

Compiler massage:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javafx.stage.Stage' available: expected at least 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to do this at all: your `ViewState` class would seem to be a model class of some kind, so it should not have references to UI elements (such as `Stage`s).

For completeness, though, here is an example that works, using `ConfigurableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory().registerResolvableDependency(...)`. Note that, since you won't be able to create the `View` object until the stage is registered, you need to make the `View` bean `@Lazy`:

```
package example;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

@Component
@Lazy
public class View {

    @Autowired
    public View(Stage stage) {
        Button close = new Button("Close");
        close.setOnAction(e -> stage.hide());
        StackPane root = new StackPane(close);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

```
package example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main extends Application {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ctx = SpringApplication.run(Main.class);
        ctx.getBeanFactory().registerResolvableDependency(Stage.class, primaryStage);
        ctx.getBean(View.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        ctx.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```